# How do I use relative paths in Taleo Connect Client?

Tags: relative-path, taleo, taleo-connect-client

Is it possible to use relative paths in a configuration file for Taleo Connect Client?

For example, let's say I have a TCC export script saved as `C:\foo\test_sq.xml`.

```
C:\
  foo\
    test_cfg.xml
    test_sq.xml
```

Later on, if I rename my folder to `C:\bar`, I'll need to manually change the script path in my config file from `C:\foo\test_sq.xml` to `C:\bar\test_sq.xml`.

Can I use a relative path instead, like `..\test_sq.xml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the built-in variable `[CFGFOLDER]` in your configuration file. For example, if your export script is in the same folder as the configuration file, you could do: `[CFGFOLDER]/test_sq.xml`

If you move your configuration file or change the folder name, the export process will still work if the configuration file and the export script are in the same folder.

Comment: Relative paths also work. You can say [CFGFOLDER]/../test_sq.xml